# ajax Success function not working, with dataType as json

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I am trying to add an attendance record for a set of students (of one classroom) using a Bootstrap modal.

Following is the code of my bootstrap modal (in which I have used the form)

```
<div id = "add_attendance_modal" class = "modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog mw-100 w-75">
        <form action="post" id = "add_attendance_form">
            <div class = "modal-content">
                <div class = "modal-header">
                    <h4 class = "modal-title">Add Attendance Record</h4>
                    <button type = "button" class = "close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                </div>
                <div class = "modal-body">
                    <div class ="form-group">
                        <div class = "row">
                            <label class = "col-md-4 text-right">Attendance Date</label>
                            <div class = "col-md-8">
                                <input type="date" name = "attendance_date" id = "attendance_date" class = "form-control" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class = "form-group" id = "student_details">
                        <div class = "table-responsive">
                            <table class = "table table-striped table-bordered">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Roll Number</th>
                                        <th>Student Name</th>
                                        <th>Present</th>
                                        <th>Leave</th>
                                        <th>Absent</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <?php 
                        foreach($students as $student)
                        {
                            ?>
                            <tr>
                                <td><?php echo $student['username']; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $student['name']; ?>
                                    <input type="hidden" name = "student_id[]" value = "<?php echo $student["id"] ?>">
                                </td>
                                <td><input type="radio" name = "attendance_status<?php echo $student['id']; ?>" checked value = "Present" /></td>
                                <td><input type="radio" name = "attendance_status<?php echo $student['id']; ?>" value = "Absent" /></td>
                                <td><input type="radio" name = "attendance_status<?php echo $student['id']; ?>" value = "Leave" /></td>
                            </tr>
                        <?php  }
                     ?>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class = "modal-footer">
                    <input type="submit" name = "add_attendance_submit" id = "add_attendance_submit" class = "btn btn-success" value = "Add Attendance" />
                    <button type = "button" class = "btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

*$students* is an array of all the students of the particular class..

Following is my Ajax code in Javascript which I am trying to work with,

```
$("#add_attendance_form").on('submit', function(event){
    event.preventDefault(); 
    $.ajax({
        url:"attendance_action.php", 
        method: "POST", 
        data: $(this).serialize() + "&action = add_attendance", 
        dataType: 'json', 
        beforeSend: function()
        {
            $("#add_attendance_submit").val("Validating...."); 
            $("#add_attendance_submit").attr('disabled', true); 
        },
        success:function(data)
        {
            
            $("#add_attendance_submit").val("Add Attendance"); 
            $("#add_attendance_submit").attr('disabled', false);
            if (data.success)
            {
                $('message_operation').html('<div class = "alert alert-success">'+data.success+'</div>');
                $('#add_attendance_modal').modal('hide');
                dataTable.ajax.reload();  
            } 
            if (data.error)
            {
                if (data.error_attendance_date != '')
                    $("#error_attendance_date").text(data.error_attendance_date);
                else 
                    $("#error_attendance_date").text('');
            }
            
        },
        error: function(e)
            {
                console.log(e); 
                alert("error"); 
            }
    });
});
```

This is the PHP code in attendance_action.php

```
if (isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == "add_attendance")
{
    $attendance_date = '';  
    $error_attendance_date = ''; 
    $output = ''; 
    $error = 0; 
    if ($_POST['attendance_date'] == '')
    {
        $error_attendance_date = "Attendance Date is Required..."; 
        $error++; 
    }
    else 
    {
        $attendance_date = $_POST['attendance_date'];
    }
    if ($error > 0)
    {
        $output = array(
                    "error"                 => true, 
                    "error_attendance_date" => $error_attendance_date
        );
    }
    else 
    {
        $student_id = $_POST['student_id'];
        $results = check_attendance_records($student_id[0], $attendance_date);
        if ($results->rowCount() > 0)
        {
            $output = array(
                        'error'             => true, 
                        'error_attendance_date' => 'Attendance data already exists on this data'
            );
        }
        else 
        {
            for ($count = 0; $count < count($student_id); $count++)
            {
                $data = array(

                    ':student_id'               => $student_id[$count],
                    ':attendance_status'        => $_POST["attendance_status".$student_id[$count].""],
                    ':attendace_date'           => $attendance_date
                    );
                $db->insert_to_attendance_table($data, $id); // Where $id is teacher id

            }
            $output = array(
                'success'               => 'Data Added Successfully'
            );
        }
    }
    echo json_encode($output); 
}
```

And finally, here is the database function being used in the *attendance_action.php* (in case if anyone needs to take a look at it)... They are defined in a Database class, of whose $db is an object.

```
 public function check_attendance_records($student_id, $date)
    {
      $data = array();
      $sql = "select * from junc_attendance where student_id = :student_id AND date = :date";

      $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql); 
      $data['classroom_id'] = $classroom_id; 
  $stmt->execute($data);
      $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
      return $result; 
    }
    public function insert_to_attendance_table($data, $teacher_id)
    {
      $class_data = get_classroom_details($teacher_id);
      $classroom_id = $class_data['id'];
      $sql = "INSERT INTO jnc_attendance(classroom_id, date, student_id, status) VALUES (:attendance_date, :classroom_id, :student_id, :attendance_status)";
      $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
      $stmt->execute(['classroom_id' => $classroom_id], $data);
      return true;
    }
```

I need the data in form of json and hence I have used the dataType as json.

I have used three different conditions, first one checks if the attendance date is empty... Second one checks if the attendance date is already used and third one is the success condition, if everything goes right. But the ajax function gives error on all the conditions and always call the *error* function instead of *success* function.

Can anyone help me out and point out the error? I would be very thankful.
I tried to use the console.log(e) command in the error field, but I couldn't understand anything at all.

I also checked the *Netwrok* from the Tools and the data being sent to the server looks perfect, however I never got any response from the server in the Network, which I should be getting in form of json.

Data sent to the attendance_action.php (as seen from Network in Tools)
*I didn't select any date and hence the attendance_date is empty here.*

```
attendance_date: 
student_id[]: 2
attendance_status2: Present
student_id[]: 3
attendance_status3: Present
student_id[]: 4
attendance_status4: Present
action :  add_attendance
```

From the console.log(e), this is what I get (this is a pretty long response, I don't understand it at all however :/ )

```
{readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: ƒ, getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ, setRequestHeader: ƒ, overrideMimeType: ƒ, …}
abort: ƒ (e)
always: ƒ ()
catch: ƒ (e)
done: ƒ ()
fail: ƒ ()
getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ ()
getResponseHeader: ƒ (e)
overrideMimeType: ƒ (e)
pipe: ƒ ()
progress: ƒ ()
promise: ƒ (e)
readyState: 4
responseText: ""
setRequestHeader: ƒ (e,t)
state: ƒ ()
status: 200
statusCode: ƒ (e)
statusText: "OK"
then: ƒ (t,r,i)
__proto__: Object
```

I can open any of these and all of them go into a never-ending loop on *proto*. Can't understand why however... Tried to search this error, found out that what I need to do is return my data in json form, but I am already doing it.

*This is what I got, on opening "done" a little bit... This can further be opened but similar fields appear still *

```
done: ƒ ()
arguments: (...)
caller: (...)
length: 0
name: "add"
prototype:
constructor: ƒ ()
__proto__:
constructor: ƒ Object()
arguments: (...)
assign: ƒ assign()
arguments: (...)
caller: (...)
length: 2
name: "assign"
__proto__: ƒ ()
apply: ƒ apply()
arguments: (...)
bind: ƒ bind()
call: ƒ call()
caller: (...)
constructor: ƒ Function()
length: 0
name: ""
toString: ƒ toString()
Symbol(Symbol.hasInstance): ƒ [Symbol.hasInstance]()
get arguments: ƒ ()
set arguments: ƒ ()
get caller: ƒ ()
set caller: ƒ ()
__proto__: Object
[[FunctionLocation]]: <unknown>
[[Scopes]]: Scopes[0]
[[Scopes]]: Scopes[0]
caller: (...)
create: ƒ create()
defineProperties: ƒ defineProperties()
defineProperty: ƒ defineProperty()
entries: ƒ entries()
freeze: ƒ freeze()
fromEntries: ƒ fromEntries()
getOwnPropertyDescriptor: ƒ getOwnPropertyDescriptor()
getOwnPropertyDescriptors: ƒ getOwnPropertyDescriptors()
getOwnPropertyNames: ƒ getOwnPropertyNames()
getOwnPropertySymbols: ƒ getOwnPropertySymbols()
getPrototypeOf: ƒ getPrototypeOf()
is: ƒ is()
isExtensible: ƒ isExtensible()
isFrozen: ƒ isFrozen()
isSealed: ƒ isSealed()
keys: ƒ keys()
length: 1
name: "Object"
preventExtensions: ƒ preventExtensions()
prototype: {constructor: ƒ, __defineGetter__: ƒ, __defineSetter__: ƒ, hasOwnProperty: ƒ, __lookupGetter__: ƒ, …}
seal: ƒ seal()
setPrototypeOf: ƒ setPrototypeOf()
values: ƒ values()
__proto__: ƒ ()
[[Scopes]]: Scopes[0]
hasOwnProperty: ƒ hasOwnProperty()
isPrototypeOf: ƒ isPrototypeOf()
propertyIsEnumerable: ƒ propertyIsEnumerable()
toLocaleString: ƒ toLocaleString()
toString: ƒ toString()
valueOf: ƒ valueOf()
__defineGetter__: ƒ __defineGetter__()
__defineSetter__: ƒ __defineSetter__()
__lookupGetter__: ƒ __lookupGetter__()
__lookupSetter__: ƒ __lookupSetter__()
get __proto__: ƒ __proto__()
set __proto__: ƒ __proto__()
```

Comment: Please add the output of `console.log(e)`, so we can identify the issue more easily.

Comment: `$('message_operation')` should probably be `$('#message_operation')`

Comment: @DreiDe I have added it in the end of the main post. Not sure If it is clear enough however... It's a way too long error to be completely shared here... Also added the data being sent to the server from Network

Comment: @Barmar oh yes, thank you! Fixed it, but still no good result (although it wouldn't affect the success function either because it's inside it. So to get there, success fuction must execute first, as far as my understanding is)

Comment: Of course, I never suggested that this was a fix, just something I noticed.

Comment: If you're getting an empty response, the PHP script may be failing. Check your PHP error log.

Comment: @Barmar yes, I just tried it. There was an error of PARSE in the check_attendance_records ( I can't do it the way I was doing it ), however I have now fixed it.... Thank you! First time I actually checked PHP errors from the logs data, lol. It still however didn't fix anything. The error is still there... Moreover, that PHP function was only used in case of successful insertion of data, other two cases (where if attendance date is repeated or is empty) weren't linked with that function. And they were and are still showing the error.

Comment: Add `echo` statements to the PHP to make sure it's running. This will break the JSON parse, but since that's not working anyway it doesn't matter.

Comment: yes, I did try it previously as well... I tried again now just to be sure, it shows nothing.. I added an echo "yes" statement right after the if (isset($_POST['action']....) statement and it didn't show up in the console... Changed the dataType to text and it still didn't show up in the console. Also tried using e = e.trim() [it worked for me once earlier] but this time it showed an error that trim() is not a valid function. Not sure why.. I also tried to change the action value when sending data (and then in if condition in PHP attendance_action file) but again, no help

Comment: It seems to me that the error was in how I was sending the action... I was sending it as action = add_attendance.... I now tried sending it without any space (action=add_attendance) and it has worked! Thank you for the help, really appreciate it! ^_^ There have other issues appeared up now lol, but I will fix them up hopefully :) Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try adding header

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

after

```
if (isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == "add_attendance") {
```

Comment: Since he uses `dataType: 'json',` it will assume it's JSON without the header.

Comment: Tried it, it didn't work... Tried removing dataType: 'json' and replaced it with 'text', that didn't work either... Shouldn't work too because I am returning data in JSON form